# Efficient Sum of Primes

Tags: java, programming-challenge, primes

I wrote this simple implementation of the sum of primes for the code eval

> Challenge Description:
>
> Write a program which determines the sum of the first 1000 prime numbers.

I would like to know of a better - more efficient - way of implementing the solution.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class SumOfPrimes {

    public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
        if (n < 2) {
            return false;
        }
        if (n == 2) {
            return true;
        }
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt((double) n); i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 1, count = 0; count < 1000; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                sum += i;
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }

}
```

As for the primality test I only know of these other:

```
for (int divisor = 2; divisor < n; divisor++) {
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

and

```
for (int divisor = 2; divisor <= n/2; divisor++) {
    if (n % divisor == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 8):

You've written a very literal and straightforward implementation to solve the challenge: test numbers for primality, and accumulate them until you have 1000 of them.

However, when you want to find many prime numbers, an algorithm such as the [sieve-of-eratosthenes](/questions/tagged/sieve-of-eratosthenes) is more efficient than repeated trial division.  [Here is a benchmark](/a/77572/9357) that illustrates the difference.  Your program follows the same basic outline as @Legato's solution, except that you haven't implemented some optimization hacks.  If you just want to sum the first 1000 primes, there isn't much of a difference in execution time, but your program will not scale up as gracefully as a sieve algorithm.

Answer (score 7):

The challenge description does not explicitly require you to check if the numbers are prime by yourself. So the most efficient way would probably be like this:
1. Store the first 1000 prime numbers in an array.
2. Sum up all elements of that array.

But that's not the goal of the challenge I guess. So here is a real improvement:

- Store `Math.sqrt((double) n)` in a local variable to ensure it is calculated only once per odd number.
- Start your main method with `sum = 2`, `count = 1` and `i = 3`. Now you can remove `if (n < 2)` and `if (n == 2)` from your isPrime method. This saves you two checks per number.

Comment: In addition to your last point: If you change `i++` in the loop to `i += 2`,  you can also drop the `if (n % 2 == 0)`.

Comment: I don't like the idea of making `isPrime` wrong because it knows the assumptions that `main` makes. If you've removed those initial checks because the main method doesn't require them, then `isPrime(1)` will return `true` when somebody else calls it later, and that's just not right. The preconditions need to stay in `isPrime`.

Comment: @MillieSmith: In general you are right of course. In this case I think it is a valid improvement because nobody will use his method and the task was to find prime numbers fast. In my opinion it is valid to create a method that has a specific contract. The method should have a comment informing the clients about the usage.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach needs some modifications that will improve efficiency. However, it will not matter for too few iteration (like 1000), so you will get the same results for both approaches. But if you are trying the same solution for, say, 10000 iterations, then you will get somewhat better performance.

Your code with my changes:

```
 import java.lang.Math;

 public class SumOfPrimes {

public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    int x = (int)Math.sqrt(n);
    for (int i = 3; i <= x; i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    long sum = 2;
   long x = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 3, count = 1; count < 1000; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }
    } 
    System.out.println("Sum is "+sum);
    System.out.println("Time elapsed :"+System.currentTimeMillis()-x);
 }
}
```

Here I have changed the loop condition as you are calling the method each time the loop iterates. I have calculated the prime numbers starting from 3.

`System.currentTimeMillis()` is used to check the time elapsed for an operation. For 1000 iterations or fewer, you will not get any difference, but if you increase the value of `count < 1000` to `count < 100000`, you will see significant changes. I checked for `count < 100000` using your way and I got this output:

> ```
> Sum is 62260698721
> Time elapsed :581
> ```

And using the changed one, I got:

> ```
> Sum is 62260698721
> Time elapsed :254
> ```

Comment: I don't see how this is reviewing the code -- to me, it looks more like you gave your own solution.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes : i have not given my solution!! i have changed few things in question only which should be there to improve performance

Comment: Then explain how you changed it, rather than saying "i changed your code as : [sic]" and dumping the modified code.

Comment: Your code is wrong, actually. I just tested it (See **[here](http://ideone.com/b36Nhe)**) and it says that 2 isn't prime. You'll need to add back the `== 2` check.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes : question was not related to find particular number is prime or not! its about finding sum of first 1000 prime number.

Comment: And to find the sum of the first thousand, you need to correctly identify the first thousand. This doesn't do that.

Comment: Anyway, let's forget about the bug in your code -- _it won't even compile._ Go ahead, try it. Copy/paste your badly-indented, buggy code into your favorite editor and try to compile. It won't.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't want to run a full sieve first, then there are a couple of improvements I can see in the `isPrime()` function:

First, you can combine your second and third tests into one:

```
if (n < 2) {
   return false;
}

if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return n == 2;
}
```

Second, with a little more work, you can skip multiples of 3 in your main loop by using a 2-4 wheel:

```
// Handle multiples of 3.
if (n % 3 == 0) {
    return n == 3;
}

// Handle multiples of 5, 7, 11, ...
int testDivisor = 5;
double limit = Math.sqrt((double) n);
int step = 2;
while (testDivisor <= limit) {
    if (n % testDivisor == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Step 2, 4, 2, 4 ... alternately.
    testDivisor += step;
    step = 6 - step;
}
```

The resulting stream of `testDivisor`'s is prime rich, because it eliminates all even numbers and multiples of 3, like 9, 12, 15 etc.  It still contains a few composites, such as 25, 35, 49, but it does reduce wasted divisions.  To completely eliminate all composite numbers you need to set up a large enough sieve right at the start.

The `while` loop could be coded as:

```
for (int testDivisor = 5; testDivisor <= limit; testDivisor += step, step = 6 - step) { ... }
```

but I think that is less readable.  YMMV.